# CSRF Token is obtainable from a cookie when running locally, but is not found when the backend is deployed as an Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, csrf, nancy

I'm having an issue with retrieving the CSRF token from the cookie when my frontend connects to my backend. My backend is C# with an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Service app utilizing Nancy Modules. My frontend is Typescript utilizing Axios to communicate with the backend.

While running locally, the CSRF cookie is obtainable and the token is extracted and sent back in the request headers. When connecting to the deployed Azure App Service backend, the cookie still exists but is no longer visible by the frontend, so it is unable to send the token back in the headers.

I have inspected the responses with Postman as well as the Dev Tools in Chrome to verify that the cookie is being added and have made sure that the HttpOnly flag has not been set for the cookie on creation.

Here is the code sample for how I add the CSRF cookie:

```
        protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        Nancy.Security.Csrf.Enable(pipelines);

        var corsURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsURL"];

        pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(context =>
        {
            var ncsrfCookie = new NancyCookie("default", "default");
            if (context.Items.ContainsKey("NCSRF"))
                ncsrfCookie = new NancyCookie("NCSRF", context.Items["NCSRF"].ToString(), false, false);

            if(ncsrfCookie.Name != "default" && context.Response.Cookies.Contains(ncsrfCookie) == false)
                context.Response.Cookies.Add(ncsrfCookie);

            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsURL);
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, NCSRF");
        });
    }
```

And here is the code for extracting the token in the frontend:

```
    getCsrfCookie(): string{
    try{
        console.log(document.cookie);
        var csrfCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        console.log(csrfCookies);
        var filteredCookies = csrfCookies.filter((item) => item.includes('NCSRF='));
        console.log(filteredCookies);
        var value = filteredCookies[0].replace("NCSRF=", "");
        return decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    catch(err){
        throw new Error("Error with NCSRF: " + err);
    }
}
```

The console logs are there for debugging and the output for document.cookie is currently a single cookie that is added by Axios.

I've tried doing some research and the majority of suggestions were ensuring the the httponly flag was set to false, which is done when the cookie is created.

Comment: sounds like a CORS issue - compare the sent cookie's domain name, it might be different than your domain

Comment: I went ahead and added the proper domain to the cookie, and I am still receiving the same error